# open word print preview page by c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I intend to send ajax from chrome to c# controller, and use c# to open a word document and switch to print preview,
just as clicking ctrl+p in word 2010/2013.

```
sendKeys.Send ("^p")
```

was tried, and it only triggers word 2003 style print dialog box.

Inserting macro into word document doesn't work either.

Is there a way I can achieve it? Thanks!

Edited:
What I would prefer is as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PrintDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) class

Comment: Hi this picture shows what i want.[link](https://postimg.org/image/6rqoubioz/)
Seems PrintDialog is different from this?